# URLrewrite cross-site errors

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite my base URL from `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`, so that requests to `http://example.com/dir/file.ext` do not get caught by cross-site access errors.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Now this checks perfectly with everything I have read (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), but it's not rewriting the URL in the browser address bar, and I'm still getting the cross-site auth errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (your htaccess is in document root directory):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$       http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, what does this do and what was wrong with my attempt?

Comment: Well to be honest, your code should work. I changed http_host pattern (which should not change the problem) and i added an optional slash in rewriterule (could be the problem). Try it and let me know

Comment: Your code works, mine doesn't. This must be it. Thanks!